# Can files be created in Pivotal Cloud Foundry environment

Tags: spring-boot, ftp, spring-integration, cloud-foundry

i have deployed an application into the pivotal cloud using Spring Integration  ,where it should read file and create more files in another folder based on custom logic , and after that is has to ftp those output files to remote directory  .The scenario works perfectly fine in local machine ,but in the cloud it doesn't do as expected .Any insights are welcome!Thanks !!

My doubts are -- Since it has to create files in cloud ,is it possible ? are any configurations needed ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `Volume Services`:

> This topic describes how Pivotal Cloud Foundry (PCF) app developers can read and write to a mounted file system from their apps. In PCF, a volume service provides a volume so your app can read or write to a reliable, non-ephemeral file system
>
> Before you can use a volume service with your app, your Cloud Foundry administrator must add a volume service to your deployment. See the Enabling NFS Volume Services topic for more information.

Here: https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-10/devguide/services/using-vol-services.html

Answer (score 0):

You can standup an s3 compatible object storage like [minio](https://github.com/minio/minio).

And then create a s3-service CUPS and use it in your app. Here's an article that can help with it - https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/cf-s3-demo.